# Get td value and compare to an input value with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with the class `.client-data` which contains lots of rows and cells. I want to search the cells and compare if the inner text matches an input value and if true I want to jump the the nearest `<tr>` tag to the cell that matched the input. I am very new to jQuery so I may be way off here but so far I have the following code:

```
    $('.client-data td').each(function findNext() {

        var cellText = $(this).html();    
        var inputVal = $('#findField').val();
        var goTo = cellText.closest('tr').attr('id');

        if (cellText == inputVal) {
            $(document).scrollTop( $(goTo).offset().top );  
        }
    })
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Use `$(this).text();` to get the text

Comment: and what is the issue ?

Comment: Thanks - gave that a go but doesn't seem to be making a difference.

Comment: The problem is that when run the function nothing is happening - I'm wondereing if it's just a syntax error perhaps in the way I've compared the variables in the if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose this is your html:

```
<input type="text" id="i">
<table class="client-data">
<tr>
<th>Month</th>
<th>Savings</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>January</td>
<td>$100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Feb</td>
<td>$100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>March</td>
<td>$100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mafdrch</td>
<td>$100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mafsarch</td>
<td>$100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Macrch</td>
<td>$100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mabxrch</td>
<td>$100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mcxbarch</td>
<td>$100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mxcbarch</td>
<td>$100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mcbbxcarch</td>
<td>$100</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

your script for searching and scrolling:

```
  // trigger on keyup
 $("#i").keyup(function(){
  var input = $(this).val();
  // scroll to first td that has the input val
  $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".client-data td:contains('"+input+"')").first().offset().top
  }, 500);
})
```

check it out in action here: https://jsbin.com/toyecarigo/edit?html,console,output

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much